# Adding image and border to a layout in Android

Tags: android, image, xamarin, border

There are many useful links here describing how to add a border to layout in android and there also others describing how to add a image as background to a layout. But they are working seperately.
I have a textview in my app and I want to add a background image to it and also a border.
I searched around but haven't found anything.
Here is the seperate code for my XML files:
**Background Image**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/TitlePattern"
android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

**Border:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#635E5E" />
<padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

How can I give my textview both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [layer-list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList). Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <color android:color="#ffffff" />
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <bitmap
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/TitlePattern"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include your textview with background, inside a layout with border

Comment: It tried out that, but it seems that this doesn't work, because the image is overlaying the border of the layout.